# flutter-web how to check what kind of browser user using?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

hey guys i have a problem with my flutter web project

it is, if user accesses the project with in-app-browser(ex. instagram, twitter)
it displays crashed UI

so i need to make an Dialog that shows, the link needs to open with other kinds of browser besides in-app-browser

so the first thing what I need to find out is what kind of browser user access from
but I don't know how to debug it from

is there anyone who ever tried this kind of work??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try both renderers seperately?

This could be the solution maybe.

Try building the html-renderer version and the canvaskit seperately, maybe there is an issue with this in the in app-browsers.

Comment: thx but already have tried, we are using html-render because we have an image error issue when we try to render it with cavasKit and wasn't  able to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

I think using kIsWeb should work.

Documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kIsWeb-constant.html

tl:dr

```
if (kIsWeb) {
  // running on the web!
} else {
  // NOT running on the web! You can check for additional platforms here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use this package - [web_browser_detect](https://pub.dev/packages/web_browser_detect)